# AJAX : Why Autosuggest(given) is not working?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I got the plugin from the net and made some required changes. But I think PHP is not responding.

*exp1.html code*

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>AutoSuggestion using Ajax, Jquery and PHP</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="exp1.css">
</head>

<body>
<div class="serch-wrap">
    <div class="form-wrapper cf">
        <input type="text" class="abhijitscript" name="search_word">
        <input type="submit" value="Search">
    </div>
    <div class="autodropdown">
        <ul class="suggestresult"></ul>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="exp1.js"></script>

</html>
```

exp1.php

```
<?php
$host="localhost";
$user="root";
$password="jatin";

$link=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password);
if(@mysqli_select_db($link,'books')){
// echo "Database connected..<br>";
}
else
echo mysqli_connect_error();


if(isset($_POST['name']))
{
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,trim($_POST['name']));
$sql = "SELECT `name` FROM `books` WHERE `name` LIKE 'l%'";
$myquery = mysqli_query($link,$sql) or die(mysql_error());
if(mysqli_num_rows($myquery) !=0)
{
    while(($row = mysqli_fetch_array($myquery)) !== false)
    {
        echo '<li>'.$row['name'].'</li>';
    }
}
else
{
    echo '<li>Not Found</li>';
}
} else{
echo "not set!";
}
?>
```

exp1.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.abhijitscript').keyup(function(){
    var query_string = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "exp1.php",
        data: { name:query_string },
        success: function(data)
        {   console.log(data);
            $('.suggestresult').html(data);
            $('.suggestresult li').click(function(){
                var return_value = $(this).text();
                $('.abhijitscript').attr('value', return_value); 
                $('.abhijitscript').val(return_value);
                $('.suggestresult').html('');
            });
        }
    });
});
});
```

Console also not showing any error, which points to some mistake in php code. I have provided complete code. Thank you!

Comment: try this `$sql = "SELECT 'name' FROM 'books' WHERE 'name' LIKE '%$name%'";`

Comment: That wasn't working actually, that's why I replaced it with 'L'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited your code a bit and it is working fine for me now.

```
<?php
$host="localhost";
$user="root";
$password="jatin";

$link=@mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password);
if( !$link || !@mysqli_select_db($link,'books')){
    echo mysqli_connect_error();
    exit ;
}

if(isset($_POST['name'])) {
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,trim($_POST['name']));
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT(`name`) FROM `books` WHERE `name` LIKE '%{$name}%'";
    $myquery = mysqli_query($link,$sql) or die(mysql_error());
    if(mysqli_num_rows($myquery) !=0) {
        while(($row = mysqli_fetch_array($myquery)) !== NULL) {
            echo '<li>'.$row['name'].'</li>';
        }
    } else {
        echo '<li>Not Found</li>';
    }
} else {
    echo "not set!";
}
?>
```

Comment: So you are able to perform autosuggest or you tested only php file?

Comment: I did not made any other changes, just edited the PHP file. I tested using the 3 files above. but I would change the query using '%{$name}%' to make a search which use any part of the name file. vs start with like '$name%' does.

Comment: I don't know what's the problem but it still ain't working for me...May be problem is in JS file. because console is just showing "Navigated to http://localhost/exp1.html"

Comment: Right, I made another change for you, DISTINCT statement in the SQL query and mysqli_fetch_array !== NULL, not !== false

Comment: I think your post URL is wrong. Can you please check your url. Do you have use any directory inside of the `htdocs` directory?

Comment: The main issue was while(($row = mysqli_fetch_array($myquery)) !== false). If using !== which is the strict comparaison operator, it should be !== NULL. Don't forget to accept the answer ;)